# Extracting certain elements from a ragged array

Tags: list-manipulation

For the following let me use this notation:

$\qquad \text{data}=\{\{x_1,y_{11}\}, \{x_1,y_{12}\},\{x_1,y_{1N}\},\,\dots,\,\{x_2,y_{21}\}, \{x_2,y_{22}\},\{x_2,x_{2M}\},\,\dots\}$,

where $M\neq N$. What I'm trying to find are the smallest values, $\{\{x_1,y_{11}\}, \{x_2,y_{21}\},\dots\}$, and the largest values, $\{\{x_1,y_{1N}\}, \{x_2,y_{2M}\},\,\dots\}$

As an example, expressed in the Wolfram Language:

```
data = 
 {{0.2,0.255556}, {0.2,0.411111}, {0.2,0.566667}, {0.2,0.722222}, {0.2,0.877778}, {0.2,1.03333}, {0.2,1.18889}, {0.2,1.34444}, {0.2,1.5},
  {0.4,0.411111}, {0.4,0.566667}, {0.4,0.722222}, {0.4,0.877778}, {0.4,1.03333}, {0.4,1.18889}, {0.4,1.34444}, {0.4,1.5},
  {0.6,0.566667}, {0.6,0.722222}, {0.6,0.877778}, {0.6,1.03333}, {0.6,1.18889}, {0.6,1.34444}, {0.6,1.5}, 
  {0.8,0.722222}, {0.8,0.877778}, {0.8,1.03333}, {0.8,1.18889}, {0.8,1.34444}, {0.8,1.5}, 
  {1.,1.03333}, {1.,1.18889}, {1.,1.34444}, {1.,1.5},{1.2,1.18889}, {1.2,1.34444}, {1.2,1.5}, {1.4,1.5}}

SmallestValues = 
  {{0.2, 0.255556}, {0.4, 0.411111}, {0.6, 0.566667}, {0.8, 0.722222}, {1., 1.03333}, {1.2, 1.18889}, {1.4, 1.5}}
BiggestValues = 
  {{0.2, 1.5}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.5}, {0.8, 1.5}, {1., 1.5}, {1.2, 1.5}, {1.4, 1.5}}
```

My problem is that I honestly can't think of a way to get this done in Mathematica. I'm used to python coding and there I would probably change the type from a list to something like a matrix and then manipulate this using for-loops, but this seems rather inefficient and is presumably not necessary here.

Comment: Do you mean "from" instead of "form"?

Answer (score 6):

```
Join @@ Values @ GroupBy[data, First, MinimalBy[Last]]
```

> {{0.2, 0.255556}, {0.4, 0.411111}, {0.6, 0.566667}, {0.8, 
>       0.722222}, {1., 1.03333}, {1.2, 1.18889}, {1.4, 1.5}}

```
Join @@ Values @ GroupBy[data, First, MaximalBy[Last]]
```

> {{0.2, 1.5}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.5}, {0.8, 1.5}, {1., 1.5}, {1.2, 
>       1.5}, {1.4, 1.5}}

Answer (score 3):

If your `data` is guaranteed to be ordered consecutively for the same $x$, then:

```
groups = SplitBy[data, #[[1]] &];
SmallestValues = groups[[All, 1]];
BiggestValues = groups[[All, -1]];
```

If not, you can look into `GroupBy` function and the code will be similar.

Answer (score 3):

This works even if the data are out of order:

`g = Gather[Sort[data], #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &];`

`Map[Sort, g][[All, 1]]`

> {{0.2, 0.255556}, {0.4, 0.411111}, {0.6, 0.566667}, {0.8, 
>     0.722222}, {1., 1.03333}, {1.2, 1.18889}, {1.4, 1.5}}

`Map[Sort, g][[All, -1]]`

> {{0.2, 1.5}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.5}, {0.8, 1.5}, {1., 1.5}, {1.2, 
>     1.5}, {1.4, 1.5}}

Answer (score 3):

```
KeyValueMap[List]@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Min]
```

> {{0.2, 0.255556}, {0.4, 0.411111}, {0.6, 0.566667}, {0.8, 0.722222}, {1., 1.03333}, {1.2, 1.18889}, {1.4, 1.5}}

```
KeyValueMap[List]@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Max]
```

> {{0.2, 1.5}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.5}, {0.8, 1.5}, {1., 1.5}, {1.2, 1.5}, {1.4, 1.5}}

Both at once:

```
KeyValueMap[List]@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, MinMax]
```

> {{0.2, {0.255556, 1.5}}, {0.4, {0.411111, 1.5}}, {0.6, {0.566667, 1.5}}, {0.8, {0.722222, 1.5}}, {1., {1.03333, 1.5}}, {1.2, {1.18889, 1.5}}, {1.4, {1.5, 1.5}}}

You can leave out the `KeyValueMap[List]@` part and only use the `GroupBy` part if you want to have an association instead of a list.

Answer (score 3):

You may compose a few functions together to collect your results. There are a few ways to compose the functions.

With `Query` and `RightComposition`

```
{smallest, biggest} = 
 Query[GroupBy[First -> Last] /* KeyValueMap[Thread[{##}] &] /* Transpose, MinMax]@data
```

With `Map` and `Prefix`.

```
{smallest, biggest} = 
 Transpose@KeyValueMap[Thread[{##}] &, MinMax /@ GroupBy[First -> Last]@data]
```

Both give

> ```
> {
>  {{0.2,0.255556},{0.4,0.411111},{0.6,0.566667},{0.8,0.722222},{1.,1.03333},{1.2,1.18889},{1.4,1.5}},
>  {{0.2,1.5},{0.4,1.5},{0.6,1.5},{0.8,1.5},{1.,1.5},{1.2,1.5},{1.4,1.5}}
> }
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
mm = Merge[MinMax] @ MapApply[#1 -> {##2} &] @ data;

AssociationThread[{"Min", "Max"} -> #] & /@ mm // Dataset
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SortBy` and `SplitBy`:**

```
data = {{0.2, 0.255556}, {0.2, 0.411111}, {0.2, 0.566667}, {0.2, 
    0.722222}, {0.2, 0.877778}, {0.2, 1.03333}, {0.2, 1.18889}, {0.2, 
    1.34444}, {0.2, 1.5}, {0.4, 0.411111}, {0.4, 0.566667}, {0.4, 
    0.722222}, {0.4, 0.877778}, {0.4, 1.03333}, {0.4, 1.18889}, {0.4, 
    1.34444}, {0.4, 1.5}, {0.6, 0.566667}, {0.6, 0.722222}, {0.6, 
    0.877778}, {0.6, 1.03333}, {0.6, 1.18889}, {0.6, 1.34444}, {0.6, 
    1.5}, {0.8, 0.722222}, {0.8, 0.877778}, {0.8, 1.03333}, {0.8, 
    1.18889}, {0.8, 1.34444}, {0.8, 1.5}, {1., 1.03333}, {1., 
    1.18889}, {1., 1.34444}, {1., 1.5}, {1.2, 1.18889}, {1.2, 
    1.34444}, {1.2, 1.5}, {1.4, 1.5}};

t1 = data // SortBy[#, First] & // SplitBy[#, First] & // Map[First]
t2 = data // SortBy[#, First] & // SplitBy[#, First] & // Map[Last]

Prepend[
  Join[t1, t2, 2][[All, {1, 2, 4}]]
  , {"First", "Min", "Max"}] //
 Grid[#
   , Alignment -> {Left, Left, Left, Center}
   , ItemSize -> {{3, 5, 2}, 1}
   ] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method using `GatherBy`:

```
(x |-> {First /@ x, Last /@ x})@GatherBy[data, First]
```

Both give:

```
 {
 {{0.2,0.255556},{0.4,0.411111},{0.6,0.566667},{0.8,0.722222},{1.,1.03333},{1.2,1.18889},{1.4,1.5}},
 {{0.2,1.5},{0.4,1.5},{0.6,1.5},{0.8,1.5},{1.,1.5},{1.2,1.5},{1.4,1.5}}
 }
```